# I am trying to output { key, list(values) } in MapReduce but I am only getting sorted {key,value} pairs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My requirement is the following

```
input file 
key    value
eid    ename
1      a
2      b
3      c
```

o/p file

```
key   values
eid   1,2,3
ename a,b,c
```

I wrote the logic in my mapper using header array and data array and 
case1: Without Reducer (i.e. setNumReduceTasks(0))

case2: Using Default Reducer

in both cases I am just getting the o/p as

```
eid   1
eid   2
eid   3
ename a
ename b
ename c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to use a reducer. The reason is, you want all the records with `eid` to go to the same reducer and all the records with `ename` to goto the same reducer. This will help you in aggregating the `eid` and `ename`.

If you just use the mapper (without reducers), then it is possible that, different `eid` may goto different mappers.

Following code achieves this:

```
package com.myorg.hadooptests;    

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class EidTest {

    public static class EidTestMapper
            extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text , Text, Text > {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String line = value.toString();
            String[] words = line.split("\t");

            if(words.length == 2) {
                context.write(new Text("eid"), new Text(words[0]));
                context.write(new Text("ename"), new Text(words[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class EidTestReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String finalVal = "";

            for (Text val : values) {
                finalVal = finalVal.concat(val.toString()).concat(",");
            }

            finalVal = finalVal.substring(0, finalVal.length() - 1); // Remove trailing comma
            context.write(key, new Text(finalVal));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "EidTest");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(EidTestMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(EidTestReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/in/in9.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/out/"));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

For your input, I got the output (the mapper assumes that key/values are tab separated):

```
eid     3,2,1
ename   c,b,a
```